# is it possible to run CDO within a R script?

Tags: r, cdo-climate

I am working with netcdf files, and there are some analysis that I've been doing with CDO and then, with R. I would like to know if there would be possible to "call" the CDO directly from R, in the same script. I am not sure how (I have been trying with System()  to invoke the commands..but I don't get it). Anyone has an idea about that?? Would it be possible??

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Have you seen this [package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/cmsaf/index.html)?

Comment: Yes, and actually it seems really good, but there are some functionalities that CDO can make and I didn't find them in that package. That's why I was interested in knowing if it's possible to run CDO within R.

Comment: The `system` function lets you run almost anything from R. The question is whether `<anything>` can interoperate.

Answer (score 2):

Since 2018, there is now a R package called "ClimateOperators" that allows you to use CDO and NCO operators directly from within R without resorting to system commands.  Here is a link to the github repository:

https://github.com/markpayneatwork/ClimateOperators

Answer (score 1):

Yes, using the `system()` function you can use bash (in Linux) along R normal routines

For example, a simple code to convert a GRIB2 file to NetCDF

```
file_grb2 = "001.grb2"
file_ncdf ="001.nc"
system(paste("cd ~/DATA/prate; cdo -f nc copy ",file_grb2,file_ncdf,sep=(" ")))
```